# Inline Forms Twitter Bootstrap + Simple Form + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

As the title suggests I'm using Bootstrap with Simple_Form. I'm trying to get `:thumbnail_layout_horizontal` & `:thumbnail_layout_vertical` on the same line but can't seem to figure it out?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shop, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :store, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :product_id, :as => :hidden %>

  <%= f.input :has, :wrapper => :prepend, :label => 'Has' do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "#", :class => "add-on" %>
    <%= f.input_field :has %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :published, :as => :boolean %>
  <%= f.input :thumbnail_layout_horizontal, input_html: { class: 'span1' }, :collection => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"], :label => false %>
  <%= f.input :thumbnail_layout_vertical, input_html: { class: 'span1' }, :collection => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"], :label => false %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap them in a div named `controls-row`

As per the examples on bootstrap sites http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Such as:-

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <%= f.input :thumbnail_layout_horizontal, input_html: { class: 'span1' }, :collection => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"], :label => false %>
    <%= f.input :thumbnail_layout_vertical, input_html: { class: 'span1' }, :collection => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"], :label => false %>
</div>
```

I think you'd want to have different values for your spans, i.e. not both span1

Comment: Thanks that's getting closer however they are still not aligned correctly.